# I'm looking to modify values in a list of dictionaries.

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

## The values to be modified are not the same key:value combos that would be searched for to indicate #that this dictionary is to be modified. Here is the code I tried:

```
employees = [
      {
        "first_name": "Bill", 
        "last_name": "Lumbergh",
        "job_title": "Vice President",
        "hire_date": 1985,
        "performance_review": "excellent"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Michael", 
        "last_name": "Bolton",
        "job_title": "Programmer",
        "hire_date": 1995,
        "performance_review": "poor"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Peter", 
        "last_name": "Gibbons",
        "job_title": "Programmer",
        "hire_date": 1989,
        "performance_review": "poor"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Samir", 
        "last_name": "Nagheenanajar",
        "job_title": "Programmer",
        "hire_date": 1974,
        "performance_review": "fair"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Milton", 
        "last_name": "Waddams",
        "job_title": "Collator",
        "hire_date": 1974,
        "performance_review": "does he even work here?"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Bob", 
        "last_name": "Porter",
        "job_title": "Consultant",
        "hire_date": 1999,
        "performance_review": "excellent"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Bob", 
        "last_name": "Slydell",
        "job_title": "Consultant",
        "hire_date": 1999,
        "performance_review": "excellent"
      }
    ]

employees[0]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[1]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[2]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[3]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[4]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[5]['review_finished'] = 'yes'
employees[6]['review_finished'] = 'yes'

def update_file(employees):
    for dict in employees:
        for k, v in dict.items():
            if [k]['first_name'] == 'Bill':
                dict [v]['performance_review'] = 'poor'
            elif [k]['job_title'] == 'Consultant':
                dict[v]['performance_review'] = 'poor'
            else:
                dict[v]['performance_review'] = 'excellent'



update_file(employees)
```

This is the error that comes up:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brend\Documents\GA.py\problem1.py", line 70, in 
    update_file(employees)
  File "C:\Users\brend\Documents\GA.py\problem1.py", line 60, in update_file
    if [k]['first_name'] == 'Bill':
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `dict` variable is a dictionary, and `k,v` are tuples where `k` is they key name, and `v` is the value. When you type `[k]['first_name']`, you are trying to index a list (which is `[k]`) using a string (`['first_name']`) which is why you get the error. What you want to do can be rewritten as

```
def update_file(employees):
    for dict in employees:
        if dict['first_name'] == 'Bill':
           dict['performance_review'] = 'poor'
        elif dict['job_title'] == 'Consultant':
           dict['performance_review'] = 'poor'
        else:
           dict['performance_review'] = 'excellent'
```